# computing concordance index with ranger (R package)

Tags: r, random-forest, survival-analysis

I'm trying to use predictions from a random survival forest computed using Ranger to calculate a c-index at specific time points. I know this can be done easily for a coxph model with the following code:

```
  cox_model = coxph(Surv(time, status == 1) ~ ., data = train)
  c_index_test  <- pec::cindex(cox_model, formula = Cox_model$formula, data=test, eval.times= c(30, 90, 730)) 
#want to evaluate at 1 month, 3 months, and 2 years
```

However, although I can calculate a c-index at these time points easily with a random forest generated using `rfsrc()`, I haven't been able to do it using ranger.

In addition to the pec `cindex()` function (which doesn't work with objects of class "**ranger**", I've also tried the concordance.index function (part of the survcomp package) and tried different combinations of using the predict.ranger function to generate survival probability predictions, but nothing has worked.

If anyone can provide code as to how to calculate a the c-index of a ranger RSF (*at specific time points and on an external validation set*) I would appreciate it immensely!!! I've been able to do it with randomforestSRC but it just takes so long that often my R session will time out and I haven't actually been able to get ANY results with runs having >10 trees...

Answer (score 0):

The ranger packages computes Harrell’s c-index, which is similar to the concordance statistic. If you have a fitted model `rf`, the attribute `prediction.error` is equivalent to `1 - Harrell's c-index`. Have a look at the following [link](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/09/25/survival-analysis-with-r/) for more details.